# Escaping placeholder in Yeoman generator

Tags: placeholder, yeoman-generator

I am trying to use Yeoman to create a generator for a web app and I have *.jsp and *.gradle files which I want to be generated (sometimes just copied) during bootstrapping. Unfortunately Yeoman throws an error when there are JSP comments in *.jsp files like `<%@ ... %>` or when there are placeholders like `${ .. }` in *.gradle files.

I guess the reason of the error is that Yeoman treats this entries like placeholders to be processed but it cannot find appropriate values so it throws.

How can I overcome this? How can I escape or disable processing of some kind of placeholders?

I still want to use EJS-styled placeholder `<%= .. %>` in the same files though.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on maven properties where I have to use `${propertyname}`.

I solved it by using the following for templates.

```
this.template('_pom.xml', 'pom.xml', null, { 'interpolate': /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g });
```

I'm new to yeoman so I don't know what `{ 'interpolate': /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g }` does but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to render jsp tags like:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

you could use `<%%` which prints a literal `<%`

So change the previous line for:

```
<%%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

That solved my code without making adhocs. The same solution can be applied to other scenarios.

Comment: Worked for me ! Thanks a lot! :)